# Volatile with synchronized together

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there any reason to use volatile and synchronized together in this code?

```
public class Helper {
  private volatile int n;
  private final Object lock = new Object();
  public Helper(int n) {
    this.n = n;
  }

  public void setN(int value) {
    synchronized (lock) {
      n = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Class Helper must be thread safe. I've got this example from the "Java Concurrency Guidelines" book, but it is still not clear: what is the reason for using volatile and synchronized together in this example?

Comment: What is the exact book you talk about? I would strongly advice the Java Concurrency in Practice book (http://jcip.net/) to learn Java concurrency.

Comment: I'v found this book here (Page 167)
http://www.sei.cmu.edu/reports/10tr015.pdf

Everything in this book is quite clear except this case only

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of this example is to point out that `syncronized` without `volatile` isn't enough in this case given the fact that object can be published unsafely (i.e. without `volatile` in `Foo`):

> If the helper field in the Foo class is not declared volatile, the n field should be declared volatile so that a happens-before relationship is established between the initialization of n and the write of Helper to the helper field. This is in compliance with guideline “VNA06-J. Do not assume that declaring an object reference volatile guarantees visibility of its members” on page 35. This is required only when the caller (class Foo) cannot be trusted to declare helper volatile.

That's correct, but they chose a bad example to demonstrate it, because `volatile` without syncrhonization is enough in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to put the synchronised block around the change in value; since Java 5 this is done "automatically" for volatile variables.  I think that previous to Java 5, it was not necessarily the case.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the volatile is used because 'n' is set in the constructor

Comment: Yes, but what reason to use synchronized in setN method?

Comment: Oh really? I don't know how to invoke constructor of the same object from 2 or more threads, do you?

Comment: I dont know too) My question was about why synchronization needed in setN method. If n variable is volatile, setter can be without any additional synchronization. Or not?